# Hash Dereference in Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, hash, multidimensional-array, dereference, template-toolkit

I've got a multi-dimensional hash that I'm trying to print out in a table.  I can't get the referencing / dereferencing right.

I'm putting an excel spreadsheet into the hash and I want to print out the corresponding rows and columns in html and match the rows/columns of the spreadsheet (some of which are empty).

I'm using **Perl Dancer** and **Template Toolkit**.  On the server side the hash works fine.  `print $big_table{$column}{$row};` on the server side and it prints the correct column and row with NO issues.

On the client side, the `0, 1, 2...` are supposed to be the columns.  Some columns are blank so I can't just print the contents.

The way it is now it prints ARRAY(0x3e5389c).  I tried a different way and it printed HASH...

I know I've got some reference/dereference issues.  Any advice would be welcome.

Server Side Code:

```
my %big_table = ();

# $cell->value() is the text ripped from the excel cell at that location
$big_table{$column}{$row} = $cell->value();

template 'index', { big_table => \%big_table };
```

Client Side:

```
<Table border="3">
<% FOREACH n IN big_table.0 %>

<TR><TD>&nbsp<% big_table.0.keys %>&nbsp<TD>&nbsp<% big_table.1.keys %>
&nbsp<TD>&nbsp<% big_table.2.keys %>&nbsp<TD>&nbsp<% big_table.3.keys %>
&nbsp <TD>&nbsp<% big_table.4.keys %> 
&nbsp<TD>&nbsp<% big_table.5.keys %>&nbsp

<% END %>
</Table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Got it working.

Changed from a hash to an array. '$big_table[$col][$row] = $cell->value();' and populated a second array with all the row #'s.

The Client looks like 

    <% FOREACH r IN row_numbers %>
    <TR><TD> &nbsp <% big_table.0.$r %> &nbsp <TD> &nbsp <% big_table.1.$r %>...
    <% END %>

Works great but it's probably crazy in-effecient :(.  The spreadsheet is 800 rows long so it's  a 2nd array with 800 elements just to iterate over 'FOREACH' loop.

Comment: Post your results as an answer and mark it accepted.

Comment: Inefficient?! Why do you think it's less efficient to iterate over 800 array indexes than 800 hash keys?

Comment: Not more or less efficient for that.  I meant that I created an ADDItional array that I populated with the $row locations just because I could get the dereference working right.

Comment: I tried posting an answer earlier but it wouldn't let me.  I don't have enough street-cred or something...  I guess I waited long enough because it lets me now.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

Changed to an array. '$big_table[$col][$row] = $cell->value();' and populated a second array with all the row #'s.

The Client looks like

```
<% FOREACH r IN row_numbers %>
<TR><TD> &nbsp <% big_table.0.$r %> &nbsp <TD> &nbsp <% big_table.1.$r %>...
<% END %>
```

Works great but it's probably crazy in-effecient :(.  The spreadsheet is 800 rows long so it's  a 2nd array with 800 elements just to iterate over 'FOREACH' loop.